# Fatal error LNK1181: Cannot open input file 'DelayImp.lib'

Tags: node.js

Hello I am trying to compile `canvas` node module for my project but getting error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'DelayImp.lib' [\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]`

My VS install and Build Tools is ok, and updated to latest version, `DelayImp.lib` is in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64\delayimp.lib"`

Thank you.